# How to avoid $cookies getting deleted when refresh page or change window location?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to maintain session in frontend. However, I found out that whenever I refresh the browser or change `window.location` . The cookie disappears.

```
      angular
        .module('myservices')
        .factory('myAuthentication', Authentication);

      Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http', '$q', '$rootScope'];

      function Authentication($cookies, $http, $q, $rootScope){

        var Authentication = {
          login                    : login,
          getAuthenticatedAccount  : getAuthenticatedAccount,
          isAuthentiate            : isAuthentiate,
          setAuthenticateAccount   : setAuthenticateAccount,
          unAuthenticate           : unAuthenticate,
        };

        return Authentication;

        function login(email, password){
          $http.post('login/', {
            email: email, password: password
          }).then(loginSuccess, loginError);
          function loginSuccess(response){

            Authentication.setAuthenticateAccount(response.data);

            $rootScope.$broadcast('login', "login");

            // changing window location will delete the cookies
            window.location = '/';
          }
          function loginError(response){
            console.log('error');
          }
        }

        function getAuthenticatedAccount(){
          if (!$cookies.authenticatedAccount){
            return ;
          }
          return JSON.parse($cookies.authenticatedAccount);
        }

        function isAuthentiate(){
          return !!$cookies.authenticatedAccount;
        }

        function setAuthenticateAccount(account){
          $cookies.authenticatedAccount = JSON.stringify(account);
        }

      }
```

I tested this in both firefox and safari and I make sure that I tested both unchecked and checked disable cache in firefox.

Is there any other setting in angular that keep the cookie persistant?

Comment: Which version of AngularJS? Version 1.4+ suggest using the [getters and setters of $cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies). In addition to that, there's `putObject` and `getObject` APIs which should eliminate the need to use JSON.stringify and parse.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rb08wgha/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the "expires" attribute which intimates that when to expire the cookie, Find the following code through which you can set the cookie expiration time:

$.cookie(

```
"name", 
"value", 
{ 
    // The "expires" option defines how many days you want the cookie active. The default value is a session cookie, meaning the cookie will be deleted when the browser window is            closed.
    expires: 7, 
    // The "path" option setting defines where in your site you want the cookie to be active. The default value is the page the cookie was defined on.
    path: '/', 
    // The "domain" option will allow this cookie to be used for a specific domain, including all subdomains (e.g. example.com). The default value is the domain of the page where the cookie was created.
    domain: 'example.com', 
    // The "secure" option will make the cookie only be accessible through a secure connection (like https://)
    secure: true 
}
```

);